# IEnumerable<IAppointment> is causing 11 errors at class Appointments.cs

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections, ienumerable, abstract

Error:

> 'Calendar.Appointments' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.CopyTo(Calendar.IAppointment[], int)'

also same for  add, clear ,count, IsReanOnly, Remove, Indexof  etc...

Definition is :

- It must be called Appointments and it must have an empty constructor.
- It must implement the interface `IAppointments`.

The interface `IAppointments` is as follows:

```
public interface IAppointments : IList<IAppointment> 
{ 
    bool Load();
    bool Save();
    IEnumerable<IAppointment> GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime date);
}
```

The interface `IAppointment` is as follows:

```
public interface IAppointment 
{ 
   DateTime Start { get; }
   int Length { get; }
   string DisplayableDescription { get; }
   bool OccursOnDate(DateTime date); 
}
```

Because a class that implements `IAppointments` must also implement `IList<IAppointment>` (from the definition of the interface above), you might think about implementing the `Appointments` class as a sub-class of a class that implements `IList<IAppointment>` - such as `List<IAppointment>`.

I wrote:

```
 public class Appointments : IAppointments
 {
    List<IAppointment> list = null;

    public bool Load() 
    {
        bool flag = false;
        GetEnumerableList(list);
        return flag;
    }

    public bool Save() 
    {
        bool flag = false;

        return flag;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IAppointment> GetAppointmentsOnDate(DateTime day) 
    {
        List<IAppointment> day_list = new List<IAppointment>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item.Start == day) day_list.Add(item);
        }

        return day_list;
    }

    public List<IAppointment>    
    GetEnumerableList(IEnumerable<IAppointment> Enumerable)
    {
        foreach (var item in Enumerable)
        {
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

and

```
  public class Appointment : IEnumerable<IAppointment>, IAppointment
  {
      public DateTime Start { get; set; }
      public int Length { get; set; }
      public string DisplayableDescription { get; set; }

      public bool OccursOnDate(DateTime date)
      {
        return false;
      }

      IEnumerator<IAppointment> IEnumerable<IAppointment>.GetEnumerator()
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
      {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
```

but no luck and I am confused. Please can you help me how I will implement the `IEnumerated<IAppointment>` in the `Appoinments` or `Appointment` and inherit it?  I believe I am not implementing and not inheriting correctly `IAppointment` and `IAppointments` with my `Appointment` and `Appointments`.

Comment: From the looks of it, I don't think you need to inherit from `IList<IAppointment>` or `IEnumerable<IAppointment>` for `IAppointments ` and `Appointment` respectively. Otherwise please clarify your requirements.

Comment: Thank you bsarkar! I leave the  public class Appointment : IAppointment and the   public class Appointments : IAppointments without inheriting the IEnumerable<IAppointment> but i still get the errors that i mention at my message.

Comment: @Konstantinos Usually, the [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) required to show the problem shall be contained in the question itself. Any links to the full code contained somewhere else can be considered useful, but they are still secondary and just serve to provide some additional context. So if you changed something and it still doesn't work then either [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29331231/edit) your question or, after spending some time searching and evaluating, post a new one if the problem is fundamentally different.

Comment: Please do not use links to external resources, whether pages, images, etc., to support your question. External links can change or be deleted outright, rendering your question useless. Please do not use comments to provide information that you should be providing in the question. Please do make sure your question is entirely self-contained, and provide [a good, minimal, complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question.

Comment: I just want someone to explain to me. I have the Apointments class. In the Load function I want to import from a file all data to an IEnumerable<IApointment> list if it occurs to exact day. The error is that 

    'Calendar.Appointments' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.CopyTo(Calendar.IAppointment[], int)'

also same for add, clear ,count, IsReanOnly, Remove, Indexof etc... of System.Collections.Generic.ICollection.  How can I overcome this error in c# in visual studio 2013? I tried but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the Appointments class as

```
public class Appointments : List<IAppointment>, IAppointments
```

and remove

```
List<IAppointment> list = null;
```

Change `list` to `this` in your current implementation.